# Eclipse Failed to create. apk file when exporting as unsigned app?

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I am a  newbie self learning android development

I have set up and installed  the Eclipse/android sdk and ADT plugin package

All works fine including my first test  'Hello world' program that is already pre-installed when you select  new->Android Application:

This 'Hello world' application is successfully turned into a .apk file by Eclipse when exporting app as an unsigned app.

With the help of the Android tutorial directing me - 
I want to add a simple text box to my app and I have done this by adding to and altering the following files:

Firstly: I Changed the activity_main.xml file to the following:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
  android:ems="10"
  android:hint="@string/edit_message" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

secoundly: I added a string 'name' and hard coded text 'Enter a message' to the strings.xml file - so now text box object id name can be resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Gizmodo2</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
</resources>
```

My new simple app compiles o.k with the added text box and all is resolved.

But now the problem is when I now try and export app as unsigned android app, Eclipse does not generate .apk file it just generates file with extension .file!!! - Why? and how do I generate the .apk file I need from this app?

Answer (score 0):

You `EditText` definition look o.k. And this is not the cause of your problem.
There is something else. Try to move those files to a new project and run it again on the emulator to produce a new `.apk` file in the `bin` folder of this project.

By the way what happens when you run this code in the emulator?

Comment: Emulator will not start!!   seems to be working now - .apk file is suddenly being generated... but .apk file is not loading on Emulator, phone or online emulator (Manymo)

Comment: please explain what do you mean by "not start".

Comment: Also I changed the EditText android:id to edit_message as it was editText1 - which was wrong! - still does not run though??

Comment: When I say the emulator did not start I mean:  When trying to run the app using the virtual device manager I am waiting for 10 mins or more and no home screen is loading up!

Comment: it may take way over the 10 minutes, do you see the android logo?

Comment: Yes. I am seeing the android logo. Have just reduced the ram setting on advice from Eclipse - see what that does!

Comment: give it time, don't close it. sooner or later it will load.

Comment: I am giving up - it has been 50 mins and no home screen or app loading!

Comment: try to create a new AVD and run it again.